# Stopping or restarting networking results in GUI changes

Tags: linux, service, linux-mint

I've observed this behaviour in both Linux Mint 15 and 16 Cinnamon on the same machine. When I use `service` to stop `networking`, like so

`sudo service networking stop` or `restart`

it's like the GUI becomes more "basic." I'm new to Linux, so forgive my ignorance, but it seems like there's another window manager on top of a more barebones one, and for some reason that process is stopped when I stop networking.

I can restart or stop `network-manager` without any GUI changes, and it results in my networking being reset or stopped. Why can't I mess with `networking`?

Answer (score 0):

Maby this will help? 
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=92488&f=42

```
sudo service network-manager stop

sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

sudo service network-manager start
```